# How to show Function Arguments in Pycharm, other IDEs? (like in Excel...)

Tags: pycharm

Want to show function arguments (like the "arguments" that show up in Excel when one types a formula) in any python IDE:

```
type:
=find()
# and this pops up:

=find(find_text, within_text, [start_num])
```

you will get all your arguments, in the appropriate order, right away! no need to recall 10000000 formula's syntaxes!

In Excel, we see a series of parameters for the `FIND` function that are very helpful; syntax, variable requirements, so forth. I want to do this in Pycharm/python too;

suggestions?

Tried googling, searching in pycharm/s options. Is this just not feasible in Python?

thanks

Comment: Do you simply want a hint of the arguments a function accepts, as you're writing it? Then I believe Ctrl + P, Ctrl + Shift + Space, Ctrl + Shift + Enter do some of that. https://resources.jetbrains.com/storage/products/pycharm/docs/PyCharm_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 20):

#### In PyCharm:

Type the name of the function with the brackets `()`, and then place your cursor inside the brackets and type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>; This will show your the parameters for the function.

Here is a short gif showing this:

[image: Pycharm parameter info]

#### In VSCode

Vscode uses the same keyboard shortcut as IntelliJ (and by extension, Pycharm). If the shortcut does not work, you can install the key bindings extension [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=k--kato.intellij-idea-keybindings)

Example:

[image: Vscode parameter info]

#### In a REPL

Open a python repl and type:

```
help (object)
```

Where `object` can be the name of a function or class, or any object as the name suggests.

Ex:

```
➜ python                                 
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec  1 2018, 03:00:51) 
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> help(sum)
```

> Help on built-in function sum in module builtins:
>
> sum(iterable, start=0, /)
>       Return the sum of a 'start' value (default: 0) plus an iterable of numbers
>
> ```
> When the iterable is empty, return the start value.
> This function is intended specifically for use with numeric values and may
> reject non-numeric types.
> ```

```
>>> def f():
...     return 3
... 
>>> help(f)
```

> Help on function f in module __main__:
>
> f()

```
>>>
```

The help page pops up and you can read any documentation associated with the object.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. 

the "Help()" function does show some code and gives a concise explanation of the function's function, but DOES NOT show the arguments within the formula

What I would aim for would be: when we first type something (ie. ("Print(" we see:

"Print(values,sep,end,file,etc)" but this vanishes the second you type the first Parenthesis.

Comment: PyCharm should show arguments if you press _Ctrl+P_ and type parameters.

Comment: for Mac users the command might be _cmd_ + _P_, depending on the key scheme used

Comment: This doesn't show or list the parameters.